# past simple vs. past perfect

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

Here is a paragraph from a school English textbook for high school students in Taiwan.

> Apart from its natural splendor, Kyoto has so much more to feast one's
> eyes on. Having previously been the capital of Japan for over a
> thousand years, the city boasts a large number of historic shrines and
> temples.

According to the textbook, the second sentence is reduced from the adverbial clause:

> Because the city **had** previously **been** the capital of Japan for
> over a thousand years, it boasts a large number....

I wonder whether the full form of the clause should be in the simple past:

> Because the city **was** previously the capital of Japan for over a
> thousand years, it boasts a large number...

In the first and second paragraph, no information regarding other capitals of Japan before or after Kyoto is mentioned, so I wonder why the textbook says the second sentence is originally in the past perfect tense. I think the past simple should suffice.

Comment: It's misleading to suggest that second sentence is somehow "reduced" from an alternative phrasing. As it happens, the (syntactically optional) initial ***having been*** adverbial clause does indeed give a ***reason*** for the assertion that follows, so ***because*** is part of an accurate rephrasing for that *exact* context. But that wouldn't be true with syntactically identical contexts such as ***Having been** known as "Peking" for many decades, the city now goes by the name "Beijing"* - where ***because*** would make no sense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you, and I think the textbook is wrong.  We would say "Kyoto *was*", because it's an event in the past, without any other time reference in the sentence.

"Kyoto *had been*" implies that it was in the past *before another event in the past*, and we don't see any other reference to an event in the past.  *Had been* would only be used in a sentence like "When Commodore Perry came to Japan, Kyoto *had been* the capital of Japan for over one thousand years."

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question, stangdon. It helps me understand how to use the past perfect even better. Many thanks.